# Browse button not working in software gui

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt

I am working on a GUI for a software that automates Data Entry for different clients, right now I am implementing the first client called Galicia and I cannot get the browse button to work, which is supposed to allow the user to browse for a file where the data is stored at. At the moment its not really even reacting as a button. (By default, in PyQt buttons have a blue border overlay when hovered by mouse, and not even that responds.)

Here is my code

```py
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QLabel, QComboBox, QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon, QStandardItemModel, QStandardItem
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication, QMainWindow, QWidget, QLabel, QLineEdit,
    QPushButton, QFileDialog, QProgressBar
)
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QThread, pyqtSignal, QSize
from analysis import analyze


class WorkerThread(QThread):
    progress_changed = pyqtSignal(int)

    def run(self):
        # Here you can put your own code to be executed in the main loop
        for i in range(101):
            self.progress_changed.emit(i)
            self.msleep(50)


class GaliciaGUI(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()


        central_widget = QWidget(self)


        self.search_label = QLabel("Search for a file:", central_widget)
        self.search_label.setGeometry(50, 50, 170, 30)

        self.search_button = QPushButton("Browse", central_widget)
        self.search_button.setGeometry(50, 80, 80, 30)
        self.search_button.clicked.connect(self.browse_file)

        self.date_start = QLabel("Fecha:", central_widget)
        self.date_start.setGeometry(350, 50, 170, 30)

        self.date_start_input = QLineEdit(central_widget)
        self.date_start_input.setGeometry(350, 80, 250, 30)

        self.date_start_input = QLineEdit(central_widget)
        self.date_start_input.setGeometry(50, 150, 200, 30)
        self.date_start_input.setEchoMode(QLineEdit.Password)

        self.selected_file_label = QLabel("", central_widget)
        self.selected_file_label.setGeometry(50, 80, 300, 30)

        self.password_label = QLabel("Enter password:", central_widget)
        self.password_label.setGeometry(50, 120, 150, 30)

        self.password_input = QLineEdit(central_widget)
        self.password_input.setGeometry(50, 150, 200, 30)
        self.password_input.setEchoMode(QLineEdit.Password)

        self.start_button = QPushButton("Start", central_widget)
        self.start_button.setGeometry(50, 190, 80, 30)
        self.start_button.clicked.connect(self.start_main_loop)

        self.progress_bar = QProgressBar(central_widget)
        self.progress_bar.setGeometry(50, 230, 300, 30)
        self.progress_bar.setValue(0)

        self.status_label = QLabel("", central_widget)
        self.status_label.setGeometry(50, 250, 150, 30)

        self.file_path = None
        self.worker_thread = WorkerThread()
        self.worker_thread.progress_changed.connect(self.update_progress_bar)

    def browse_file(self):
        file_path, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(
            self, "Select a file", "", "All Files (*);;Text Files (*.txt)"
        )
        if file_path:
            self.selected_file_label.setText(f"Selected file: {file_path}")
            self.file_path = file_path

    def start_main_loop(self):
        password = self.password_input.text() or None
        if self.file_path:
            self.worker_thread.start()
            analyze(self.file_path, password)

    def update_progress_bar(self, value):
        self.progress_bar.setValue(value)
        if value == 100:
            self.status_label.setText("Success")


class LandingPage(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle('Client Selection')
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 400, 300)
        
        self.client_label = QLabel('Select a client:', self)
        self.client_label.move(50, 50)
        
        self.client_dropdown = QComboBox(self)
        self.client_dropdown.addItems(['Galicia', 'Client 2', 'Client 3'])  # Add more clients here
        self.client_dropdown.move(150, 50)
        
        self.submit_button = QPushButton('Submit', self)
        self.submit_button.move(150, 100)
        self.submit_button.clicked.connect(self.open_gui)
        
        self.galicia_gui = None  # Initialize instance variable for GaliciaGUI
        
        self.show()
    
    def open_gui(self):
        client = self.client_dropdown.currentText()
        if client == 'Galicia':
            self.galicia_gui = GaliciaGUI()
            self.galicia_gui.setGeometry(100, 100, 700, 600)
            self.galicia_gui.activateWindow()
            self.galicia_gui.raise_()
            self.galicia_gui.show()
            app = QApplication.instance()
            app.setActiveWindow(self.galicia_gui)
        elif client == 'Client 2':
            # Open Client 2 GUI
            pass  # Replace client
        elif client == 'Client 3':
            # Open Client 3 GUI
            pass  # Replace with client
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    landing_page = LandingPage()
    app.exec_()
```

I tried to implement a button which brings up the file explorer (This software is meant for windows) where one can browse for the needed file and then said file is inputed into the data processing via the analyze function.

Comment: The `selected_file_label` is not visible, but it is there and it is covering the browse button. If you comment out that label the button is reachable again.

Comment: May I also suggest that you look into using layouts. Hardcoding the coordinates of your widgets is not really a viable way of creating a GUI.

Comment: @mahkitah okay thanks for the answer and i will look into your suggestion, thank you very much!

Answer (score -3, accepted):

### it's fixed check

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QLabel, QComboBox, QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon, QStandardItemModel, QStandardItem
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication, QMainWindow, QWidget, QLabel, QLineEdit,
    QPushButton, QFileDialog, QProgressBar
)
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QThread, pyqtSignal, QSize
# from analysis import analyze


class WorkerThread(QThread):
    progress_changed = pyqtSignal(int)

    def run(self):
        # Here you can put your own code to be executed in the main loop
        for i in range(101):
            self.progress_changed.emit(i)
            self.msleep(50)


class GaliciaGUI(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()


        central_widget = QWidget(self)


        self.search_label = QLabel("Search for a file:", central_widget)
        self.search_label.setGeometry(50, 50, 170, 30)

        # self.browse_file()

        self.date_start = QLabel("Fecha:", central_widget)
        self.date_start.setGeometry(350, 50, 170, 30)

        self.date_start_input = QLineEdit(central_widget)
        self.date_start_input.setGeometry(350, 80, 250, 30)

        self.date_start_input = QLineEdit(central_widget)
        self.date_start_input.setGeometry(50, 150, 200, 30)
        self.date_start_input.setEchoMode(QLineEdit.Password)

        self.selected_file_label = QLabel("", central_widget)
        self.selected_file_label.setGeometry(50, 80, 300, 30)

        self.password_label = QLabel("Enter password:", central_widget)
        self.password_label.setGeometry(50, 120, 150, 30)

        self.password_input = QLineEdit(central_widget)
        self.password_input.setGeometry(50, 150, 200, 30)
        self.password_input.setEchoMode(QLineEdit.Password)

        self.start_button = QPushButton("Start", central_widget)
        self.start_button.setGeometry(50, 190, 80, 30)
        self.start_button.clicked.connect(self.start_main_loop)

        self.progress_bar = QProgressBar(central_widget)
        self.progress_bar.setGeometry(50, 230, 300, 30)
        self.progress_bar.setValue(0)

        self.status_label = QLabel("", central_widget)
        self.status_label.setGeometry(50, 250, 150, 30)

        
        self.search_button = QPushButton("Browse", central_widget)
        self.search_button.setGeometry(50, 80, 80, 30)
        self.search_button.pressed.connect(lambda: self.browse_file())

        self.file_path = None
        self.worker_thread = WorkerThread()
        self.worker_thread.progress_changed.connect(self.update_progress_bar)

    def browse_file(self):
        file_path, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(
            self, "Select a file", "", "All Files (*);;Text Files (*.txt)"
        )
        if file_path:
            self.selected_file_label.setText(f"Selected file: {file_path}")
            self.file_path = file_path

    def start_main_loop(self):
        password = self.password_input.text() or None
        if self.file_path:
            self.worker_thread.start()
            analyze(self.file_path, password)

    def update_progress_bar(self, value):
        self.progress_bar.setValue(value)
        if value == 100:
            self.status_label.setText("Success")


class LandingPage(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle('Client Selection')
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 400, 300)
        
        self.client_label = QLabel('Select a client:', self)
        self.client_label.move(50, 50)
        
        self.client_dropdown = QComboBox(self)
        self.client_dropdown.addItems(['Galicia', 'Client 2', 'Client 3'])  # Add more clients here
        self.client_dropdown.move(150, 50)
        
        self.submit_button = QPushButton('Submit', self)
        self.submit_button.move(150, 100)
        self.submit_button.clicked.connect(self.open_gui)
        
        self.galicia_gui = None  # Initialize instance variable for GaliciaGUI
        
        self.show()
    
    def open_gui(self):
        client = self.client_dropdown.currentText()
        if client == 'Galicia':
            self.galicia_gui = GaliciaGUI()
            self.galicia_gui.setGeometry(100, 100, 700, 600)
            self.galicia_gui.activateWindow()
            self.galicia_gui.raise_()
            self.galicia_gui.show()
            app = QApplication.instance()
            app.setActiveWindow(self.galicia_gui)
        elif client == 'Client 2':
            # Open Client 2 GUI
            pass  # Replace client
        elif client == 'Client 3':
            # Open Client 3 GUI
            pass  # Replace with client
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    landing_page = LandingPage()
    app.exec_()
```

[display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YoxjY.jpg)

( Don't forget to validate answer. thank you )

Comment: No, it certainly is ***NOT*** fixed, you just inverted the problem, because now `selected_file_label` is covered by the button and will not be readable when `browse_file()` is called. The *only* appropriate solution is to properly use [layout managers](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).